# Given three quantum states, how to compute the triple product of amplitudes $\sum_i u_i v_i w_i$?

Tags: linear-algebra, swap-test, hadamard-test

Assume I have three quantum states $|u\rangle$, $|v\rangle$ and $|w\rangle$ which can be obtained with three quantum circuits $U$, $V$ and $W$.

We know that we can easily estimate the inner product $\langle u|v\rangle$ or with any of the three states by using an Hadamard or a swap test.

But, what if I wanted to estimate the result of the triple multiplication of the amplitudes of the three states, that is $\sum_i u_i v_i w_i$ (you can assume the amplitudes are real)?

Comment: The SWAP test gives you a way to estimate for $|\langle u\vert v\rangle|^2$, which does not depend on the global phase of either $\vert u\rangle$ or $\vert v\rangle$. 

The issue with your quantity is that it if I add a global phase of $-1$ to one of the three input vectors, it changes the result.

Comment: echoing the other comment: you don't, and can't, estimate the inner product $\langle u|v\rangle$. You estimate the squared overlap, which you can see as estimating an observable (in particular, the SWAP) on the state $|u\rangle\otimes |v\rangle$. On the other hand, estimating $u_i v_i w_i$, or $u_i v_i$ for that matter, cannot have such form, and therefore cannot be directly estimated by linear postprocessing of measurement data. And more generally, if the quantity you care about depends on individual global phases, then it's not a physical quantity. Unless you allow for entangled input states

Comment: @glS what do you mean with "entangled input states"?

Comment: to be honest, I'm not sure. I don't remember what I was thinking when writing that and it's a bit of a vague comment. There is no way to access global phases because they simply don't exist; they're an artifact of describing things via kets. You can see if very easily rewriting things in the density matrix formalism, where global phases do not appear at all

Comment: I am not very skilled about quantum mechanics and I don't know what a density matrix is. So, there is absolutely no way to compute a trilinear product?